# Docker run asp.net core image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-desktop

I have simple asp.net core app with `/students` endpoint thats return test data for me. I have following docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Node.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Then, i run it using `docker run node -p 5000:5000` and expect if I go for `localhost:5000/students` I get response but I'm not.
If I do something like `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash` and then `curl 0.0.0.0:5000/students` I get response so I'm sure it's running. How can I use my app outside of container? I've tried other ports like `80` and `443` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was you have to write `docker run -p 5000:80 node` to make it work as espected because docker didn't apply any -p args